# Gephi 0.9.1. Issues in exporting edges color with sigma.js

Tags: json, data-visualization, gephi, sigma.js, sna

I'm having troubles when exporting my graph with the sigma.js module from Gephi. The JSON format doesn't store the colors of the edges. I'd like to export the color of the parent node for each edge of my graph, instead of that, I have a `"color":"rgb(0,0,0)"`

Thanks in advance for your answer

Comment: I just found this inelegant solution with **R**, to modify the Gephi json output: `library(jsonlite)`
`library(dplyr)`

`data <- fromJSON('Untitled.json', simplifyDataFrame = TRUE)`

`for (i in 1:length(data$edges$source)) {`
 `num<-as.numeric(data$edges$source[i])`
  `j<-which(data$nodes$id == num)`
  `data$edges$color[i]<-data$nodes$color[j]`
`}`

`sink("edges_colors.json")`
`cat(toJSON(data))`
`sink()`

`file.show("edges_colors.json")`